# bash ls | sort desc | take (n)?

Tags: linux, bash

What is a short way to do something like `ls` sort by date descending [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)(4) files?

Comment: Please tag your question so that people know this deals with `Microsoft` and `.Net` stuff.

Comment: Are you looking for `head -n 4`?

Comment: @arkascha What ?!!! Where is .Net ?

Comment: @AshRj in the link for `Take` he posted...

Comment: `this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion` - please explain. still got my question answered tho.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ls -rt | head -n 4` - sort by time, reverse, grab 4 first lines